# Vector Pointer weird result

Tags: c++

I just wrote code to copy a vector value of another vector and when I edit the second vector the original one should be changed.
Here is the code confusing me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int>a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector<int>* b = new vector<int>(6);
    b = &a;
    (*b).push_back(7);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        cout << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        cout << (*b).at(i);
    }
    delete b;
}
```

the question is why I get this result when I run the program:

```
1234570
123457
```

Why don't I get the last zero in both of them?

Comment: `b=&a;` -- You've just created a memory leak with that line.

Comment: Why are you using `new` to create a vector?

Comment: `cout<<a[i];` -- Change that to `cout << a.at(i);`, and then see the fireworks when `i` is equal to 5.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It's works but why?

Comment: Accessing a vector's elements out-of-bounds using `[ ]` is undefined behavior -- anything can happen, include "works".  Using `at()` the vector will check the value to see if it is within bounds, and if not, will throw an `std::out_of_bounds` exception.

Comment: *"I just write a code to copy a vector value of another vector"* - so, do that. `std::vector<int> b = a;` . Done. There is no reason whatsoever in this code for dynamic allocation of `b`. And `std::vector` is already dynamic internally, so putting the vector itself on the heap offers little (i.e. any) reward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have a serious memory leak issue. You are creating a new vector on the heap memory, and then just throw it away, without cleaning it:

```
vector<int> *b = new vector<int>(6);
b = &a;
```

Whenever you use the `new` keyword, remember to use `delete` as well:

```
vector<int> *b = new vector<int>(6);
delete b;
b = &a;
```

Or simply- avoid using `new` from the first place, if you don't need to (And if you really need, use [smart pointers](/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)):

```
vector<int> *b = &a;
```

For your question, `a` & `b` are both contain 6 elements, and when you try to print their 7th element, you trigger [Undefined Behavior (UB)](/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), which means you can see any result after `123457`, that you'll never be able to predict. You are actually trying to access an area of memory that might not belong to you.

To avoid this UB, you can use `.size()` property of your vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
```

Or in b:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b->size(); i++)
```

As [@Deduplicator](/u/3204551) suggested, simplify your code by using foreach/range loops where you can:

```
for (auto elem : b) {
    std::cout << elem;
}
```

Or for more complex collections:

```
for (auto &elem : collection) { /*...*/ }
```

Or using C++ standard library algorithm `for_each()`:

```
// Don't forget to #include <algorithm>

std::for_each(b.begin(), b.end(), (int a)[] { std::cout << a; });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. Most importantly, you have UB on this line

```
for(int i=0;i<=6;i++){
  cout<<a[i];
}
```

`a` only contains 6 elements, so you are indexing out of bounds. Don't do that, it's UB. If this happens, then your *entire* program is broken. It can do anything (including printing out the correct result).

Secondly, on this line

```
vector<int>*b=new vector<int>(6);
```

you are allocating a vector on the heap. Then on the next line

```
b=&a;
```

you are re-pointing `b`, thereby leaking the previously allocated vector.

Also, you are then `delete`ing `b`, but it's not pointing to memory that was `new`ed.

Last, but not least, please don't do `using namespace std`.

Comment: can you mention the issued and what you mean it's UB.

Comment: @FuratMostafaSmadi UB = undefined behaviour

Comment: [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) means undefined behaviour. It means you are not allowed to reason about the rest of your program.

Comment: why I must stop using namespace std ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)